# How to store an object into database using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Below is my Js, I used it to get data from a datatable

```
$("#mark_attendance").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var table = $("#attendance_table").DataTable();
        let attendance_status = [];
        $("select[name='attendance_status[]']").each(function() {
            attendance_status.push($(this).val());
        });

        let attendance_date = [];
        $("input[name='attendance_date[]']").each(function() {
            attendance_date.push($(this).val());
        });

        var data = table
            .rows()
            .data()
            .toArray();

         data = data.map((item,i)=>{
            return {
                attendance_status: attendance_status[i],...item,
            }
        })

       var  attendance_data = data.map((item,i)=>{
            return {
                attendance_date: attendance_date[i],...item
            }
        })

        // attendance_data.forEach(function(payload){
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: 'post',
                url: "/store/attendance",
                data:   {attendance_data: data},
                dataType: 'json',  
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            });
        // });


    });
```

Below is my controller

```
 public function storeAttendance(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->all();

        return response()->json('$data');
    }
```

I get the below object in my console after clicking firing the even

{attendance_data: Array(3)}attendance_data: Array(3)
0: {attendance_status: "false", id: "1", employee_name: "Admin", department_id: "2"}
1: {attendance_status: "false", id: "2", employee_name: "User", department_id: "1"}
2: {attendance_status: "false", id: "3", employee_name: "Chinyere Lynda", department_id: "1"}

Comment: We would need some more information to help you. Have you configured the connection to the DB? In which table do you want to save those data? What columns does the table have? Do you have Eloquent models defined?

Comment: A good place to start investigating would be Laravel's documentation [Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database) and [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach:

- Define the name of your html inputs exactly the same as your model attributes
- Go to the your Model and define the `$fillable` array, put there every attribute that you want to save here ( take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) )
- make a simple loop in your controller function that way :

> $attendances = $request->all();
>
> foreach($attendances as $attendance) {
>
> Attendance::create($attendance);
>
> }